# javax.comm only seems to send one message

Tags: java, device, javax.comm

I am trying to communicate from my computer to a circuit board over a serial port using `javax.comm`. I wrote a program (based on the `SimpleRead` and `SimpleWrite` examples) that will take any data received from the device and print it to `System.out` and take any line typed into `System.in` and send it to the device, followed by `\r\n`.

The device has a help function which I am using to test communications (send `hlp` and the device replies with a list of commands it will take). When I first send `hlp` I get the expected response, but the 2nd time I send `hlp` I see no response.

Is this a known problem with `javax.comm`? Or is there some sort of start-of-new-message command I need to look up and send to my device between messages?

### Further Details:

I'm using a Toshiba laptop running Windows XP.
I've hooked the board up to an oscilloscope and the "sending data" test point changes voltage when the first `hlp` is sent (this is when I see a text response in my program. however the "sending data" test point does not change voltage in response to the second and subsequent messages (when I see no text response).   Thus I am pretty sure that the issue is my program not sending the data properly (rather than my program not receiving the response properly).

The reading and writing methods of my program:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);
        String s = in.readLine();
        s = s+"\r\n";
        
        serialPort.getOutputStream().write(s.getBytes());
        serialPort.getOutputStream().flush();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch(event.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[100];
        byte[] actualBytes = null;
        try {
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                actualBytes = new byte[numBytes];
                for(int i =0; i < numBytes; i++){
                    actualBytes[i] = readBuffer[i];
                }
            }
            
            System.out.print(new String(actualBytes));
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind. This turns out to be an issue with my (limited) understanding of threading. I thought 'run()' was called continuously, but it is only called once (hence why I could only send one command). I surrounded everything in 'run()' with a 'while(true)' loop and now it works fine!